# Git Diff how to report differences in blank lines

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I'm planning on using `git diff` in my project to report differences in files for various reasons. I am interested in recording the differences to be displayed in a UI later.

For testing, I've done the following:

```sh
echo '\n\n' > 3.txt
echo '\n\n\n' > 4.txt
git diff --word-diff=porcelain --no-index --no-renames --word-diff-regex='[ \t]+|[^ \t]+' 3.txt 4.txt
```

The following is the output:

```
diff --git a/3.txt b/4.txt
index b28b04f..fd40910 100644
--- a/3.txt
+++ b/4.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@

~

~

~
~
```

The above would output nothing if `--ignore-blank-lines` is also passed, but it doesn't really output usable information if not passed as well.

There isn't any `+`/`-`/ in the above output to indicate the inserted line. Are there any parameters that can help me report blank line changes in git diff? Or would a different regex do that?

Comment: Blank line is not a word.

Comment: @0andriy I'm curious of why there is the `--ignore-blank-lines` parameter if what you are saying is blank lines are not recorded?